# Javascript/Jquery values pushing more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on building a Simon Game, similar to the one you can find here: https://codepen.io/Em-Ant/full/QbRyqq/. Relevant code snippet below and the whole of my code written so far can be found here: https://github.com/JamesRiall/Simon-Game/blob/master/js/index.js

Essentially the program is adding "red", "green", "blue" or "yellow" to the array clicksInRound whenever the relevant panel on the game is clicked. I can then use this clicksInRound array to check against the sequence the player should be following to either do nothing (if the selection is right but they haven't completed the round yet), move them onto the next level (if selection is correct and they've completed that round's sequence) or reset the game (if wrong).

My problem is that when I play through the game, the clicksInRound array is having too many values pushed to it. Below is the result of console.log of clicksInRound when I play a game and click on yellow twice (with yellow the first color in the generated sequence):

["yellow"]

["yellow"]

["yellow", "yellow"]

The output I want here is just "yellow" for the first two lines (the first click my selection is yellow in round one, and then second click my selection is yellow only so far in round two). However, I'm getting the third line ["yellow", "yellow"] which is throwing out all of my checks. If I click yellow then blue in the second round, my clicksInRound array will be ["yellow", "yellow", "blue"] when I want my output to be ["yellow", "blue"]

Can anyone diagnose the problem from the code snippet below or from my full code on GitHub? (sorry for the somewhat incomplete code snippet, it's difficult to post the relevant snippets here without just copying in the whole program).

Thanks!

```
$(".game-button").click(function() {
  if (sequencePlaying === false && running === true) {
    if ($(this).is("#red")) {
      playRedInSequence();
      clicksInRound.push("red");
      whereInRound++;
      checkClickIsCorrect();
    } else if ($(this).is("#blue")) {
      playBlueInSequence();
      clicksInRound.push("blue");
      whereInRound++;
      checkClickIsCorrect();
    } else if ($(this).is("#yellow")) {
      playYellowInSequence();
      clicksInRound.push("yellow");
      whereInRound++;
      checkClickIsCorrect();
    } else if ($(this).is("#green")) {
      playGreenInSequence();
      clicksInRound.push("green");
      whereInRound++;
      checkClickIsCorrect();
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem doesn't seem to be in your JavaScript code. In your HTML you haven't closed the div on [line 28](https://github.com/JamesRiall/Simon-Game/blob/master/index.html#L28).

```
<table style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto" id="game">
        <tr>
           <td>
              <div class="game-button" id="green"></div>
           </td>
           <td>
              <div class="game-button" id="red"><div> <!-- PROBLEM PROBLEM!! -->
           </td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
           <td>
              <div class="game-button" id="yellow"></div>
           </td>
           <td>
              <div class="game-button" id="blue"></div>
           </td>
        </tr>
   </table>
```

If you close the div and run the code , it seems to work as expected although I don't fully understand the game. Here I have created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mprtwkmn/1/) out of your github code with the correction. It seems to be working.

Comment: Thanks for the catch, but the clicks are still pushing values incorrectly. 

Basically the game generates a random sequence of length 20 consisting of red, green, blue or yellow. On round one the computer displays the first step in the sequence and you have to repeat it to move on to level two. On level two the computer displays the first two steps in the sequence and you have to repeat it in order to move on to level 3. If you get any stage in the sequence wrong then you either have to restart the level (if strict === false) or the game resets (if strict === true).